# Visual Studio Git .gitattributes text=auto ignored

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

We've been experiencing the joys of line endings after migrating SVC to Git. Mostly resolved now and looking positive. However, Visual Studio (2015 Update 3) is refusing to play nicely with changes to the gitattributes file.

We now have the following line in .gitattributes:
    `* text=auto`

Only remaining problem now is that when changing branches in Visual Studio it will show a number of changes due to line endings. However, the strange part is that if we simply run "Git Status" or open Sourcetree the changes miraculously disappear.

Has anyone experienced this or any ideas on how to resolve?

**NOTE**: This is different to the usual line ending problem in that Git through the command line or Sourcetree do not recognise these changes.